# How do I get my image to shrink as my viewport expands and contracts?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to increase as viewport increase and image to decrease as viewport decreases. I want the image to be sized relative to the browser size (i.e. ability to support multiple computer screen configurations and a mobile device). I have played around with different sizing and position fixes, but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be great. I still want the text to float on top of the image.

html

```
    <body>
  <div class="section-one">
    <img id="section-one-img"
      src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GBvmwi54ldCYsikrFDxR5MV14hiAmR_oNp3sV1yuEYcfLG084LaGDcfffJIUMgETr2E6Tdu20FpvySni5wuk7c3W6GykxW3RxJ-X0t4YcZduf2YwAOSsOYuc2cMe8KecFlvVkreZny8=w2400"
      alt="Interlaken Image Background">
    <div class="slogan">lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> lorum.</div>
</body>
```

css

```
.section-one-img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

.slogan {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: *"I am trying to get my image to shrink as my browser increases / decreases in size."* Do you mean image to ***increase*** as viewport increase and image to decrease as viewport decreases?

Comment: Anyhow, you should post code as a [mcve] -- ⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪

Comment: Yes, @zer00ne. That is what I am looking to do. Are you able to help?

Comment: Edit the question: 1. click `edit` link 2. cut code out 3. ⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪ 4. paste the HTML into the top left box. 5. paste CSS top right box. 6. save.

Comment: i didn't see the split columns, so still did one on top of another. Is that easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is fine but you are defining `.section-one-img` as a class and then using it as an id in your html.

Either change that to `#section-one-img`, or change the `<img>` tag to:

```html
<img class="section-one-img" src="..." alt="Interlaken Image Background" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the only problem is it stops expanding after 1200px. Is there any way to make that value infinite?

Comment: That's just the natural size of the image by looks of it, and you have explicitly set the `max-width` to be 100%. Replace that with `width:100%` and it will stretch to fit.